# How to call `self.class` from a mix-in module?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

I have a module to be included in other classes. It uses the [Object#class](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Object.html#method-i-class) method, like this: 
([sorbet.run link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Amodule%20M%0A%20%20def%20foo%0A%20%20%20%20self.class%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A))

```rb
# typed: true
module M
  def foo
    self.class
  end
end
```

To this, Sorbet says

```
editor.rb:4: Method class does not exist on M https://srb.help/7003
     4 |    self.class
            ^^^^^^^^^^
  Did you mean to `include Object` in this module?
    ???: Did you mean: Object#class?
```

Now it gets interesting. [Error reference for 7003](https://sorbet.org/docs/error-reference#7003) does describe that this guards against type errors in modules to be included in BasicObject. Fine, so I include Object, as the checker tells me: ([sorbet.run link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Amodule%20M%0A%20%20include%20Object%0A%20%20def%20foo%0A%20%20%20%20self.class%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A))

```rb
# typed: true
module M
  include Object
  def foo
    self.class
  end
end
```

The error message is quite unhelpful, and the linked [page #5032](https://sorbet.org/docs/error-reference#5032) does not exist.

```
editor.rb:2: Only modules can be included. This module or class includes Object https://srb.help/5032
     2 |module M
        ^^^^^^^^
```

It took me a while to realize that it's trying to tell me I cannot include a Class which is a subclass of Module. Compare with Ruby's error message:

```
$ ruby -e 'module M; include Object; end'
Traceback (most recent call last):
        2: from -e:1:in `<main>'
        1: from -e:1:in `<module:M>'
-e:1:in `include': wrong argument type Class (expected Module) (TypeError)
```

How can I make my code pass the `typed: true` level here?

Comment: For my reference, the actual code is in Yast::I18n - https://github.com/yast/yast-ruby-bindings/blob/19594f24db0fea8d4fa8b8fd4573803792686e9a/src/ruby/yast/i18n.rb#L57

Comment: I am running 0.4.4296

Comment: Thanks for the bug about the include. Fixed here: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/1047

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was actually two bugs! Thanks for pointing them out:

`class` wasn't in our shims on `Kernel`: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/1050
and we should never suggest to include something that isn't a `Module`: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/1047

Answer (score 0):

My current workaround is: ([sorbet.run link](https://sorbet.run/#%23%20typed%3A%20true%0Amodule%20ObjectInterface%0A%20%20def%20class%3B%20super%3B%20end%0Aend%0Amodule%20M%0A%20%20include%20ObjectInterface%0A%20%20def%20foo%0A%20%20%20%20self.class%0A%20%20end%0Aend%0A))

```rb
# typed: true
module ObjectInterface
  def class; super; end
end
module M
  include ObjectInterface
  def foo
    self.class
  end
end
```